# What does "referred for" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Follow instructions given to you when **referred for** medical treatment
>   for any injury and retain documentation. (https://cmpahandbook.com/all-important-safety-rules/)

What does "referred for" mean? I searched dictionary, but couldn't find the meaning. Does it mean "when given medical treatment"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means "sent for medical treatment". This is because the common procedure is that one sees a general practitioner, or perhaps an intake nurse at an ER, and that person directs, or **refers** one to a more specialized doctor or other provider. Thus one is often said to have been "referred for" treatment, even when one did not see a different medical person first. In fact, that is often called a 'self-referral".

In this context, "referred for" basically means "has been given" or "has received".

Comment: I'm not allowed to make edits of less than six characters, and I don't really see anything else wrong with your answer. I'd like to note that you have "refereed for" rather than "referred for" in your answer. Will delete this comment after you fix it as the answer author.